# Python, bybit - order not exists or too late to cancel

Tags: python, api, trading

I am trying to make a crypto bot on bybit platform which does have an API: https://bybit-exchange.github.io/docs/inverse/?python--pybit#t-cancelactive, but when trying to close the position I get this error: order not exists or too late to cancel

This is how the program runs:

*logged in*

*62338.5*

*({'ret_code': 0, 'ret_msg': 'OK', 'ext_code': '', 'ext_info': '', 'result': {'user_id': 3477310, 'order_id': 'c22d6d15-1616-4f82-84b1-672967072886', 'symbol': 'BTCUSD', 'side': 'Buy', 'order_type': 'Market', 'price': 64208.5, 'qty': 1, 'time_in_force': 'ImmediateOrCancel', 'order_status': 'Created', 'last_exec_time': 0, 'last_exec_price': 0, 'leaves_qty': 1, 'cum_exec_qty': 0, 'cum_exec_value': 0, 'cum_exec_fee': 0, 'reject_reason': 'EC_NoError', 'order_link_id': '', 'created_at': '2021-11-01T08:02:13.586Z', 'updated_at': '2021-11-01T08:02:13.586Z', 'take_profit': '0.00', 'stop_loss': '0.00', 'tp_trigger_by': 'UNKNOWN', 'sl_trigger_by': 'UNKNOWN'}, 'time_now': '1635753733.586516', 'rate_limit_status': 199, 'rate_limit_reset_ms': 1635753733583, 'rate_limit': 200}, <bravado.requests_client.RequestsResponseAdapter object at 0x000002802DF44C10>)*

c22d6d15-1616-4f82-84b1-672967072886

And here I get the error:

**({'ret_code': 20001, 'ret_msg': 'order not exists or too late to cancel', 'ext_code': '', 'ext_info': '', 'result': None, 'time_now': '1635869643.350265', 'rate_limit_status': 198, 'rate_limit_reset_ms': 1635869643348, 'rate_limit': 200}, <bravado.requests_client.RequestsResponseAdapter object at 0x000001912BDCAE50>)**

**order has been closed**

As you can see it did not close the position

And this is my code:

```
import bybit
import time


client = bybit.bybit(test=False, api_key='key', api_secret='secret_key')
print('logged in')

info = client.Market.Market_symbolInfo(symbol='BTCUSD').result()

keys = info[0]['result']
btc_original = keys[0]['last_price']
BTC_original = float(btc_original)
print(BTC_original)

#open new position
open_pos = client.Order.Order_new(side="Buy",symbol="BTCUSD",order_type="Market",qty=1, time_in_force='GoodTillCencel').result()
print(open_pos)
print(type(open_pos))

time.sleep(5)
#get order info 
order_ID = open_pos[0]['result']['order_id']
print(order_ID)
print(type(order_ID))

time.sleep(5)
#close order
close_it = client.Order.Order_cancel(symbol="BTCUSD", order_id=order_ID).result()
print(close_it)
print('order has been closed')
```

Comment: clearly that `client.Order.Order_new()` returns a tuple...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program was originaly ment to be a bot which can - stop loss and take profit + make new orders, I fixed the program by just adding the stop loss and take profit to the Create new order.

Here is the code:

```
info = client.Market.Market_symbolInfo(symbol='BTCUSD').result()

keys = info[0]['result']
btc_original = keys[0]['last_price']
BTC_original = float(btc_original)

open_pos = client.Order.Order_new(side="Buy",symbol="BTCUSD",order_type="Market",qty=1, time_in_force='GoodTillCencel', take_profit=BTC_original+10, stop_loss=BTC_original-10.result()
```